# Can I replace .attr("data"... with .data(" ...

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following:

```
        if ($(this).attr("data-disabled") === "false") {
            var $link = $(this);
            $("a.accessLink").each(function () {
                $(this).attr("data-disabled", "true");
            });
            dialog($link);
        }
```

Am I correct in saying this could be replaced with:

```
        if ($(this).data("disabled") === "false") {
            var $link = $(this);
            $("a.accessLink").each(function () {
                $(this).data("disabled", "true");
            });
            dialog($link);
        }
```

Also is there a better way for me to set all the data-disabled attributes of links with the accessLink class to a value of "disabled"?

Comment: Pretty sure this is a duplicate.

Comment: I could not understand storing $(this) in $link with statement  var $link = $(this);

Comment: I never used .data(), always attr('data-foo') -- .data() will yield unpredictable results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($(this).data("disabled") === "false") {
    $("a.accessLink").data("disabled", "true");
    dialog( $(this) );
}
```

Comment: If you use `true` and `false` as boolean you can get rid of the comparison by just doing `if (!$(this).data("disabled"))`

Comment: I know, but he's not - that's his comparison in the question.

Comment: So I don't need my each function to step through the elements?